# datatype for an iif statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

If in a SELECT statement there is the following line:

```
iif(fr.BoundID=0,'OutBound','InBound') as 'FlightBound'
```

Then when I perform a CREATE TABLE statement, should I include the actual datatype of the BoundID field which is a tinyint in the database table, or shall the datatype be varchar because I think (but not 100% sure looking at the existing code) that the previous person writing this code is saying display 'OutBound, InBound' if the ID is 0?

Comment: I think it depends on what you return in iif. In your case its VARCHAR.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers, I also have another question I need to post as come across something else in a query I've not come across before.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it will be `VARCHAR(8)`. You can always check metadata using `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
   'SELECT iif(BoundID=0,''OutBound'',''InBound'') as ''FlightBound''
   FROM #tab',NULL,0)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/413140)**</kbd>

What datatype to choose for new table `TINYINT` vs `Textual representation` is dependent on your business requirements. I would probably stay  with `TINYINT` (search for lookup table named like BoundType or ask senior developer/architect).

Answer (score 1):

The return type is the type in `true_value` and `false_value` with the highest precendence ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx), see `return types`)

> Returns the data type with the highest precedence from the types in true_value and false_value. For more information, see Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL).

Data type precendence [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) up to SQL Server 2016:

```
user-defined data types (highest)
sql_variant
xml
datetimeoffset
datetime2
datetime
smalldatetime
date
time
float
real
decimal
money
smallmoney
bigint
int
smallint
tinyint
bit
ntext
text
image
timestamp
uniqueidentifier
nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
nchar
varchar (including varchar(max) )
char
varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
binary (lowest)
```